# How to distingih between a dApp and a webapp?

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps

Is there a simpler and automatic way to check if a website or web address is a dApp? Should I check for the web3.js component on the webpage?
I can check for web3 component on chrome which has metamask but on chrome/firefox without metamask. Is there a better way?

Comment: A website in itself cannot be a Dapp. A Dapp is an application that resides on a blockchain, such as a contract on Ethereum. A website can interact with a Dapp and send transactions to a Dapp, but it is not a Dapp. I do not know how to efficiently check if a website interacts with a Dapp or not.

Answer (score -1):

Yes if there is web3 component it's for interacting with a blockchain, so it's a dapp.

Comment: Actually no. You could use web3 to get information from the blockchain without ever sending a transaction.

Comment: What's the point to get information in a blockchain if it's not a dapp ? A blockchain is a decentralized entity, if you interact with it your kind of a "decentralized app" imo.